# Adding more than one product tabs - Magento2

Tags: magento2, layout, blocks, frontend

I have created a custom product tab by [this tutorial](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/add-custom-tab-product-page-magento-2/).

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="test.tab" template="Cloudways_Mymodule::custom_tab.phtml" group="detailed_info" >
                <arguments>
                    <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Custom Tab</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

I have placed the above code in `app/code/Cloudways/Mymodule/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml` and created a template in `app/code/Cloudways/Mymodule/view/frontend/templates` which works fine and create one table on product details page.

[image: product details page]

**What if I have to add more than one tab. How should I write the XML?**

I have tried these variations but didn't work:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="test.tab" template="Cloudways_Mymodule::custom_tab.phtml" group="detailed_info" >
                <arguments>
                    <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Custom Tab</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="test_second.tab" template="Cloudways_Mymodule::custom_tab_second.phtml" group="detailed_info" >
                <arguments>
                    <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Custom Tab</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="test.tab" template="Cloudways_Mymodule::custom_tab.phtml" group="detailed_info" >
                <arguments>
                    <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Custom Tab</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="test_second.tab" template="Cloudways_Mymodule::custom_tab_second.phtml" group="detailed_info" >
                <arguments>
                    <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Custom Tab</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The working solution I have for this is:

In your catalog_product_view.xml Layout file:

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Magento_Theme::catalog/product/tabs/tab1.phtml" name="extra-tab-1" group="detailed_info">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Extra Tab 1</argument>

            </arguments>
        </block>

        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Magento_Theme::catalog/product/tabs/tab2.phtml" name="extra-tab-2" group="detailed_info">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Extra Tab 2</argument>

            </arguments>
        </block>

</referenceBlock>
```

Then just create your templates as referenced in the layout and they should appear:

[image: Tab Screenshot]

Comment: Worked!!!!!! :)

Comment: :thumbsup: Happy to help